# How to plot integral of a gradient function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, vector-calculus, integral-transforms

For $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continously differentiable and $\phi \in [0,\pi/2]$ let
$$F(x) = \int \frac{f'(x)-\cot \phi}{1+ f'(x) \cot \phi} d x$$
be a clockwise 'rotation' of $f$.
For given $f$ it is not hard to plot $\tilde f$ in mathematica.

For $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a two-dimensional generalization (in my opinion) of this mapping (in direction $\vec{1}$) is given by
$$F(x) = \int \frac{\nabla f(x)-\frac{\cot \phi}{\sqrt{2}}\vec{1}}{1+ \frac{\cot \phi}{\sqrt{2}}\nabla f(x) \vec{1}^\top} \cdot d x.$$

Using for instance `f[x_,y_]:=Exp[-x^2-y^2]`, how can we plot $F$?

**Note:** For instance $\int \nabla f(x) \cdot d x$ should look like $f$ (up to a constant) since it does not matter over which path we integrate.

**Edit:** Using a trivial path it is
$$\int_{\vec{0}}^{(u,v)} \nabla f(x) \cdot d x = \int_0^1 \nabla f(u t,v t)\cdot (u,v)  d t$$
and we can write

```
f[x_,y_]:=Exp[-x^2-y^2];
nabla[x_,y_]=D[f[x,y],{{x,y}}];
F[u_,v_]:=Integrate[nabla[u t,v t].{u,v},{t,0,1}];
Plot3D[F[u,v],{u,-1,1},{v,-1,1}]
```

But is this the best path, the best method to do it? At least it seems to work if we apply this for $F$:
[image]

Comment: The second integral s not a scalar, it is a vector, because the gradient is a vector

Comment: No, he is right, the dot in front of the differential indicates vector multiplication.

Comment: What is $\vec{1}^t$ and why to the power of $t$ ?

Comment: @flinty That's the transposed vector $(1,1)$.